# solr Indexing PDF attachments not working. in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, pdf, indexing, solr, lucene

I have a problem with integrating solr in Ubuntu server.Before using solr on ubuntu server i tested it on my mac it was working perfectly. it indexed my PDF,Doc,Docx documents.so after installing solr on ubuntu server and using the same configuration files and librairies. i've found out that solr doesn't index PDf documents.But i can search over .Doc and .Docx documents.
here some parts of my solrconfig.xml contents :

```
<lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/extraction/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-cell-\d.*\.jar" />

<requestHandler name="/update/extract"
                  startup="lazy"
                  class="solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler" >
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="lowernames">true</str>
      <str name="fmap.meta">ignored_</str>
      <str name="fmap.content">_text_</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I could have sworn I saw somebody ask you for logs, but now I can't find it.  Do you see any errors / stacktraces in the Solr logfile?

Comment: i checked the logfile in the admin interface and they were no errors.

Comment: {
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 18,
    "params": {
      "q": "*JAVA*",
      "indent": "true",
      "wt": "json",
      "_": "1453588756242"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 0,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": []
  }
}

Comment: You may need to find the actual logfile, not check logging in the admin UI.  Errors should show up in the admin UI, though.

If there are no errors, then I've got no idea what might be wrong.